# filter dictionary (dynamodb insert event)

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dictionary, amazon-dynamodb

I want to check if a dynamo db event is INSERT or not. The event looks like this:

```
{'Records': [{'eventID': '4ff7', 'eventName': 'INSERT', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'eu-central-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1637232247.0, 'Keys': {'filename': {'S': 'issues.zip'}}, 'NewImage': {'filetype': {'NULL': True}, 'filename': {'S': 'issues.zip'}, 'unixtimestamp': {'S': '1591282803734'}, 'masterclient': {'S': '100-ff0-uat'}, 'source_bucket_name': {'S': 'ems'}, 'filekey': {'S': 'incoming/100-ff0-uat/1591282803734/issues.zip'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '9000', 'SizeBytes': 232, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:table/filenames-ems/stream/2021-11-18T08:42:01.008'}]}
```

I was trying this:

```
if event['Records']['eventName'] == 'INSERT':
```

but it throws `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.
What's the best way to filter a dictionary inside a list inside a dictionary?

I also tried searching for `if value in event.values == 'INSERT'`but didnt work either

Comment: `event['Records']` is a list. Try `event['Records'][0]['eventName']` to check the first record in the event

Comment: Please accept one of the 2 correct answers or delete your question. As it stands, new readers will assume that you don't have an acceptable answer to your question yet and may waste time trying to help you. If none of the answers helped you, then update your question or respond to those answers explaining why they don't help.

Comment: i updated the qs with my own answer :) @jarmod

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow, or any Q&A website, works. You should delete your answer and accept  one of the existing, effectively identical, correct answers.

Comment: @rdas would you like to put your comment as an answer? Because that's the one i used

Comment: Also, be aware that your Lambda function might actually receive multiple records, representing multiple DynamoDB streamed records, in a single event. That's why `Records` is plural and is a list. If you use `event['Records'][0]` then you are risking ignoring 2nd and subsequent DynamoDB events. That's why the answers below are, strictly speaking, better answers.

Comment: doesn't the trigger run individually for all new incoming entries? @jarmod

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'files' (maybe you have an ingestion workflow that accepts files and writes to DynamoDB). That aside, the Lambda function can be triggered one time but include multiple DynamoDB streamed records. If your inserts/updates/deletes to DynamoDB aren't happening close to each other in time then you may rarely see this in practice, but it's a possibility. It's the nature of high performance distributed systems, and you should code accordingly, to anticipate and deal with multiple records. It's also a fairly simple change to your code. You risk missing updates if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if event['Records'][0]['eventName'] == 'INSERT':
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Since `Records` contains `list of dict`, so in order to access `eventName` you will have to loop through the list first:

Try:

```
for r in event["Records"]:
    if r['eventName'] == 'INSERT':
        # perform any process
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

`Records` is a list. You can check a specific record with `event['Records'][n]`, where `n` is the index of the record.
Or you can loop through all records to see if there exists a record with 'INSERT'.

```
events ={'Records': [{'eventID': '4ff7', 'eventName': 'INSERT', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'eu-central-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1637232247.0, 'Keys': {'filename': {'S': 'issues.zip'}}, 'NewImage': {'filetype': {'NULL': True}, 'filename': {'S': 'issues.zip'}, 'unixtimestamp': {'S': '1591282803734'}, 'masterclient': {'S': '100-ff0-uat'}, 'source_bucket_name': {'S': 'ems'}, 'filekey': {'S': 'incoming/100-ff0-uat/1591282803734/issues.zip'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '9000', 'SizeBytes': 232, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:table/filenames-ems/stream/2021-11-18T08:42:01.008'}]}

for record in events['Records']:
    if record['eventName'] == 'INSERT':
        #Do something with the record
```